# copy two columns in a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a c# question :
I have 2 datatable A and B both of them contain a column called “move” , I want to create another Datable  with 2 columns one with “move” from A the other with “move” from B , I tried something like this :

```
//cherche les last price
DataTable TickerPrice = new DataTable("Data");
TickerPrice = CheckBloomi(TickerName + " equity", "CHG_PCT_1D", FromThisTime, ToThisTime);

//cherche les last price
DataTable IndexPrice = new DataTable("Data");
IndexPrice = CheckBloomi("E300 Index", "CHG_PCT_1D", FromThisTime, ToThisTime);

DataSet MarketData = new DataSet();

DataTable Recap = MarketData.Tables.Add("Recap");
Recap.Columns.Add("Move Ticker price");
Recap.Columns.Add("Move Index price");

foreach (DataRow sourcerow in TickerPrice.Rows)
{
    DataRow destRow = Recap.NewRow();
    destRow["Move Ticker price"] = sourcerow["CHG_PCT_1D"];
    Recap.Rows.Add(destRow);
}

foreach (DataRow sourcerow in IndexPrice.Rows)
{
    DataRow destRow = Recap.NewRow();
    destRow["Move Index price"] = sourcerow["CHG_PCT_1D"];
    Recap.Rows.Add(destRow);
}
```

This work fine to copy one column (for the first foreach loop) but then for the second column I have the number shifted because I am recreating new rows.

Do you an idea of how to do that ?, let me know if it is not clear enough

Comment: How are the rows in the TicketPrice and IndexPrice tables related? ie. Does TicketPrice row 8 relate to IndexPrice row 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the both the TicketPrice and IndexPrice tables match up then you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TickerPrice.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow destRow = Recap.NewRow();
    destRow["Move Ticker price"] = TickerPrice.Rows[i]["CHG_PCT_1D"];
    destRow["Move Index price"] = IndexPrice.Rows[i]["CHG_PCT_1D"];

    Recap.Rows.Add(destRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just take the `NewRow()` and `Rows.Add()` out of the inner loop?  Something like this:

```
DataRow destRow = Recap.NewRow();
foreach (DataRow sourcerow in TickerPrice.Rows)
{
    destRow["Move Ticker price"] = sourcerow["CHG_PCT_1D"];
}

foreach (DataRow sourcerow in IndexPrice.Rows)
{
    destRow["Move Index price"] = sourcerow["CHG_PCT_1D"];
}
Recap.Rows.Add(destRow);
```

This assumes the values in TickerPrice.Rows and IndexPrice.Rows line up.